# Error " The local variable ListaNotas may not have been initialized "

Tags: java

El problema lo tengo en el **'case 1'** que la variable **'ListaNotas'** la cual me marca el error " The local variable ListaNotas may not have been initialized "y no se como solucionarlo.

```
    int salir = 0;
    int cont = 0;

    do {

        String[] opciones = { "Crear anotación", "Listar anotaciones", "Buscar", "Modificar", "Eliminar",
                "Marcar como importante", "Desmacar como importante", "Listar importantes", "Salir" };
        int opcion = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Elige una de las opciones", "ANOTACIONES",
                JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, opciones, null);

        switch (opcion) {
        case 0:
            String ListaNotas[] = new String[100];
            String NotaIntroducida = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Crear nueva nota", "Notas",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            List Lista = new ArrayList();
            Lista.add(NotaIntroducida);
            Lista = Arrays.asList(ListaNotas);

            break;

        case 1:
            
            for (int i = 0; i < ListaNotas.length; i++)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, (ListaNotas[i].toString()));

            break;
```

Comment: Estás creando `ListaNotas` en el `case 0`, por tanto, no sería reconocida en los otros `case`. Para evitar esto debes crear la variable antes de empezar el bloque `switch`. O sea, poner esto: `String ListaNotas[] = new String[100];` justo antes de   `switch (opcion) {`. Aunque no le veo mucho sentido a tu código, por ejemplo, no veo que llenes esa variable en ninguna parte ¿?

Comment: Revisa el ámbito de las variables creadas dentro de un ``case``; otro error que puedo notar es que tu variable ``Lista`` está cumpliendo la función de ``ListaNotas``.

Answer (score 0):

Según el error, seria porque la variable `ListaNotas` del case 0 no estaría inicializada, en el case 1 la inicializaste como `new String`, si la idea es usar esa variable en todas las opciones del Switch, tendrías que inicializarla fuera de este.